# How to allign "Add to Cart" button in Woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have small issue into my Woocommerce shop. I fixed different images size after Woo 3.3.3 update, but seems that buttons are misalligned. So how to make it all alligned? Example URL [here](https://phoenixfitness.dk/butik/page/2/).

[image]

I tryed this:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
margin-top:30px;
}
```

but is moving all buttons down, not only misalligned ones. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style in your active theme style.css.

```
ul.products li.product h3, .woocommerce ul.products li.product h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title{
        min-height: 38px !important;
        max-height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Added your CSS into custom CSS and saved. Still see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjY3m.png Can you check pls?

Comment: you are applying this style in above the site. right?

Comment: seems you missed one `}` for media query.

Comment: No, know what, added to Customize> Custom CSS and now works. From theme integrated CSS Editor seems that not parse correctly. Tnanks. Your answer is correct.